# SQL Timeout Period Elapsed - intermittent issue

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, timeoutexception

I am having an intermittent problem with a SQL stored procedure, that retrieves products from the SQL dB. We have around 3500 active users, and usually have around 15-30 users logged in at once, using the procedure. Over the past week, I have been getting timeout expired messages, like the one below:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) at clearance.PopulateRegularLineList(Int32 PageIndex) in e:\Websites\

The SP brings back 12 products at a time (or more if the dropdown box is selected), and runs quickly when I run it manually. This has happened maybe 20 times over the past week with different users, at different times of the day, and as such I have been unable to recreate the error when running the procedure or using test accounts to browse the site. I have read somewhere that adding NOLOCK or increasing command timeout may fix it, but that is only a quick cover-up, not a solution to the underlying problem (not to mention the poor data implications of NOLOCK).

The part of the SQL that displays the product is here:

```
    INSERT INTO @Products (WWHEAD, WWPROD, WWDESC, CTNQTY, PRC1, PRC4, [FILENAME], DPQIS, QTYL, FileReference, LineId, Price5, PriceGroup, Dimensions)                  
(SELECT A.WWHEAD, A.WWPROD, A.WWDESC, A.CTNQTY, 
        CASE WHEN @IsPrice5 = 5 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(A.Price5)) ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PRC1)) END,          
        CASE WHEN @IsPrice5 = 5 THEN A.Price5 ELSE A.PRC4 END, 
        [FILENAME],
        (CAST((DPQIS-DPALOC) AS INT)), 
        D.QTY,
        'WebImage',
        LineId,
        CASE WHEN @IsPrice5 = 5 OR A.Price5 = A.PRC4 THEN NULL ELSE A.PRICE5 END,
        LTRIM(RTRIM(PG.PriceCode)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(PG.GroupDesc)) + ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(PG.DiscDesc)),
        Dimensions
FROM    PRODUCTS A 
        INNER JOIN STOCK C ON A.WWPROD = C.DPPROD AND DPDEPO = 'CH'
        INNER JOIN PROD_COPY W ON A.WWPROD = W.WWPROD 
        INNER JOIN PRODGRP PD ON PD.GPNUM = W.WWPRGP
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS D ON D.OrderID = @OrdId AND A.WWPROD = D.ProdCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PRGRP PG ON  A.WWPCGP = PG.PriceCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODALT_GRP X ON X.ProdCode = A.WWPROD  
WHERE   A.WWBONS = 'B'
AND     A.WSID = 'WS'
AND     (LTRIM(RTRIM(A.WWHEAD)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CatHead)) OR ISNULL(@CatHead, '0') = '0')
AND     (LTRIM(RTRIM(A.WWSBHD)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CatSub)) OR ISNULL(@CatSub, '0') = '0')      
AND     (LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.WWPRGP)), 2) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@BrandT1)) OR ISNULL(@BrandT1, '0') = '0')
AND     (LTRIM(RTRIM(A.GRPTR2)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@BrandT2)) OR ISNULL(@BrandT2, '0') = '0')
AND     (LTRIM(RTRIM(A.GRPTR3)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@BrandT3)) OR ISNULL(@BrandT3, '0') = '0')        
AND     X.AltGroupCode = @ProductFilter
AND     A.PRC1 BETWEEN @MinValue AND @MaxValue
AND     A.WWHEAD <> 'B20'   
AND     (A.WWDESC Like ('%' + @SearchString + '%') OR A.WWPROD LIKE ('%' + @SearchString + '%') 
    OR A.WWPROD IN (SELECT Prodcode FROM WDS..Prod_Keywords INNER JOIN WDS..Keywords ON KeyID = KeywordID WHERE Keyword LIKE ('%' + @SearchString + '%')))                          
AND     A.WWBRN NOT IN (SELECT * from WDS.dbo.f_BrandExclusionList(@WebUserName, NULL))
AND     CAST(CASE WHEN NDATMM = '' THEN '01' ELSE NDATMM END + '-' 
            + CASE WHEN NDATDD = '' THEN '01' ELSE NDATDD END + '-' 
            + CASE WHEN NDATYY = '' THEN '1900' ELSE NDATYY END AS DATETIME) BETWEEN @threemonths AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY PD.GPSORT, A.WWHEAD, A.WWPROD, A.WWDESC, A.CTNQTY, A.PRC1, A.PRC4, [FILENAME], C.DPQIS, C.DPALOC, D.QTY, 
        LineId, A.Price5, PG.PriceCode, PG.GroupDesc, PG.DiscDesc, A.WWSBHD, A.WWBRN, 
        A.GRPTR2, A.GRPTR3, A.WWSORT, A.WWPCGP, Dimensions
HAVING  ((A.PRC1 > 20.00 AND ((DPQIS-DPALOC) > 2)) OR (A.PRC1 <= 20.00 AND ((DPQIS-DPALOC) > 8))))
ORDER BY PD.GPSORT, A.WWBRN, A.GRPTR2, A.GRPTR3, A.WWPCGP DESC, A.WWHEAD, A.WWSBHD, A.WWSORT, A.WWPROD
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How execute SP ? C# ? in SSMS ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the associated code? How many concurrent connections are made and are you sure the connection is being closed after execution is complete?